# how to interpret "this" in this example

Tags: javascript

Hello I am a javascript beginner and I read about how to interpret the `this` keyword but in this example I am still confused:

```
<script>
function example(param) {
    this.a = param;
    var b = true;

    this.getB = function() {
        return b;
    }

    this.setB = function(x) {
        b = x;
    }
}
document.write(window.a); //prints "undefined" (line A)
document.write(window.b); //prints "undefined" (line B)
document.write(window.getB(); //generates an error "undefined is not a function (Line C)"
```

For Line A, I guess the explanation is that `this` refers to the object that owns the function `example`, in this case, the window object. Therefore you can reference window.a, but it is not defined so it prints `undefined`

I cannot understand Line B. Isn't `var b` restricting b to a local scope? Which should mean that you can only reference b within the function? I was expecting Line B to generate an error, not printing `undefined`.

I have totally no clue about Line C, why does it generate an error, and what does `this` mean in this case?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: `this` depends on how you call the function. `new example().getB()`.

Comment: Keyword "this" is referred toa global scope, as you can see in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: this. _whatever_ != _whatever_, unless something is in global scope.

Comment: window.b was never defined so it prints undefined, same with window.a, you can open the console now and try window.b it will also print undefined. However, if you try window.b() as in a function, then it will give you the error since it cannot find the function

Comment: You have never actually called `example()`. None of the code inside it gets executed.

Comment: The content of `example` is irrelevant since it's never called. If you remove the whole function, you get the same result, so it has nothing to do with `this`.

Comment: asking for a missing property is fine (window.b), but asking for a missing var is an error.

Comment: thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 1):

The `this` variable depends on how the function is being used.

If you instantiate the function (treat it like a class) then `this` will refer to the instance of the class:

```
new example("foo").getB(); // `this` is an instance of example
```

If you call it with `Function.prototype.call` then `this` will refer to whatever object you passed to the `call` method:

```
example.call(anotherObject, "foo"); // `this` refers to anotherObject
```

If you just execute it directly then `this` may refer to the window or whatever other surrounding scope.

```
example("foo"); // `this` likely refers to the window object
```

You can also use `Function.prototype.bind` to wrap your function in a specific scope to help clear things up:

```
var wrappedExample = example.bind(aSpecificObject);
wrappedExample(); // Doesn't matter how it's called, `this` will refer to aSpecificObject
```

Of course you may want to consider your target browsers before using `bind` (or use a polyfill).

Comment: No problem! This is a common area of confusion for people who are new to JavaScript. :)

Comment: @user1783398 you should accept one of the answers here if it has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

First - you never call the `example()` function. So nothing it does has any effect.

Second - you have a syntax error on the last line, you are missing a `)`.

If you were to fix those issues, the results would be different:

```js
function example(param) {
    this.a = param;
    var b = true;

    this.getB = function() {
        return b;
    }

    this.setB = function(x) {
        b = x;
    }
}
example("data");
document.write(window.a); //prints "undefined" (line A)
document.write(window.b); //prints "undefined" (line B)
document.write(window.getB()); //generates an error "undefined is not a function (Line C)"
```

> For Line A, I guess the explanation is that "this" refers to the object that owns the function "example", in this case, the window object. Therefore you can reference window.a, but it is not defined so it prints "undefined"

It wasn't defined because you weren't calling the function. If you were to call it, then it is defined as the value of `param`.

> I cannot understand Line B. Isn't "var b" restricting b to a local scope? Which should mean that you can only reference b within the function? I was expecting Line B to generate an error, not printing "undefined".

The locally scoped variable `b` is distinct from the `b` property of the object that is stored in `this`.

Accessing an undefined property of an object doesn't throw an error in JavaScript, it gives you `undefined`.

If you were to access an undeclared variable, then you would have a Reference Error.

> I have totally no clue about Line C, why does it generate an error, and what does "this" mean in this case?

As with the other examples, you don't use `this` for lines A, B or C. You use `window`. `this` is only used inside the function.

You were getting an error because you never ran the function, so `window.getB` was never set. Calling the `undefined` value as a function throws an error.

If you fix the problem, as described above, you get the value of the local `b` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this within a function, it will refer to the global window object.

```
function whatsThis(){
    console.log(this); 
}
whatsThis(); //displays the window object
```

If the function exists within an object created by a constructor function, however, this will refer to the parent object

```
var WhatsThis = function(){
   this.showThis = function(){
       console.log(this);
   };
 };

 var obj = new WhatsThis();
 obj.showThis(); //displays the instance of WhatsThis
```

Likewise with object literals, this refers to the containing object.